# Colocar Imagen en body de un mail usando ASP.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

Que tal estoy usando la siguiente clase en la cúal envio un mail con algúnos datos requeridos, el problema en sí es que al adjuntar o colocar la imagen dentro de el html `<img src='carrocedis.png' style='width:40px; height:25px;'/>` en el correo no llegá dicha imagen.

```
public class SendMails {
            public static void EnviaCorreosSinOrden(int folioregistro, string numfactura ,string departamento, string incidencia, string observacion, string cantidad, string piezascjas)
            {   

                //Configuración SMTP//
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mysmtpserver");
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mail.@lob.com", "sismail22");
                client.Host = "otromail@lob.com";
                client.Port = 25;
                client.EnableSsl = false;

                //Termina Configuración SMTP//
                //Configuración del Mensaje//
                MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("sistemas@lob.local");
                mailMessage.To.Add("detinatario@lob.com");//correodpt);

                mailMessage.Body = "<div class='header'><center>" + "<img src='carrocedis.png' style='width:40px; height:25px;'/>" + "</center></div>" +
                    "<body bgcolor='#E6E6FA'><br/><br/>" +
                    "<img src='carrocedis.png' style='width:40px; height:25px;'/><br/>" +
                    "<table border='1'>"+
                    "<tr bgcolor='#00BCB4'><th>Folio</th><th>N°Factura</th><th>Incidencia</th><th>Departamento</th><th>Cantidad</th><th>Pzs/Cajas</th><th>Observación</th></tr>"+
                    "<tr><td>"+folioregistro+"</td><td>"+numfactura+"</td><td>"+incidencia+"</td><td>"+departamento+"</td><td>"+cantidad+"</td><td>"+piezascjas+"</td><td>"+observacion+"</td></tr>"+
                    "</table>"+ 
                    "<br/>"+
                    "<h4><font face='Courier'>Favor de entregar el o los documentos faltantes, si este no es el caso solicitar al proveedor correspondiente la papelería necesaria." +
                    "Gracias por su atención.</font></h4> ";
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                //mailMessage.Body = @"";
                mailMessage.Subject = "Incidencia en Recepcción de mercancia en el departamento de :" + departamento;
                client.Send(mailMessage);
                //Termina Configuración del Mensaje//

            }
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: la imagen debe estar subida en algún lado y usar la URL completa

Comment: por ejemplo tengo mis imagenes en la carpeta root/images/imagen.jpg,  coloco esa ruta ? .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En lugar de:

```
"<img src='carrocedis.png' style='width:40px; height:25px;'/><br/>" +
```

Coloca:

```
"<img src='http://www.tudominio.com/imagen/carrocedis.png' style='width:40px; height:25px;'/><br/>" +
```

Cuando vinculas imágenes, deben tener la URL accesible desde internet.